# Nuxtjs3 Vuejs3 configurations for different environment

Tags: configuration, vuejs3, environment, nuxtjs3

I am using Vue3 with Nuxt3. I have a runtime config nuxt.config.ts as follows:

```
runtimeConfig: {
  public: {
    apiHost:"http://<somehost>"
  }
}
```

I wish to override this apiHost on different environment, but nuxt compiles this config and makes them constant. (i.e. i cannot use process.env). The only way I can workaround is to use .env file and build multiple times like:

```
mkdir -p .test && rm -rf .output && mv .test .output && nuxt --dotenv environments/.test.env build && mv .output .test
mkdir -p .demo && rm -rf .output && mv .demo .output && nuxt --dotenv environments/.demo.env build && mv .output .demo
mkdir -p .prod && rm -rf .output && mv .prod .output && nuxt --dotenv environments/.prod.env build && mv .output .prod
```

This is yucky. Is there a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt 3, the runtimeConfig is indeed designed to replace the `process.env` from Nuxt 2, providing a better way to handle environment variables that can change depending on the deployment. Here’s a more streamlined way to handle different environments:

1. Make use of `.env` files: Create a `.env` file for each environment (e.g., `.env.test`, `.env.demo`, `.env.production`).
2. Use the Nuxt 3 runtime config: Update your `nuxt.config.ts` to use the public runtime configuration in a way that reads from the `.env` files.

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiHost: process.env.API_HOST // This variable has to be defined in each of your .env files
    }
  }
});
```

3. Adjust your deployment scripts: Instead of moving folders around, you can specify which `.env` file to use when running your build command. Check the documentation on how your platform supports this, but typically you can do something like:

```
NUXT_ENV=production nuxt build
```

Or, if needed, you can explicitly specify the path to your .env file for each environment:

```
nuxt build --dotenv environments/.prod.env
```

And for the static generation:

```
nuxt generate --dotenv environments/.prod.env
```

4. Handle runtime changes: If your hosting provider supports environment variables (like Vercel, Netlify, or Heroku), you can also set the environment variable directly there without having to include it in your `.env` file. This way, the `apiHost` will be picked up by Nuxt’s runtime config from the environment variable provided by your hosting environment.

By using the above approach, you will only build once, and at runtime, the correct `apiHost` value will be used based on the environment variables set in your deployment environment. This saves time and resources as you avoid multiple builds and the manual juggling of output directories.

Comment: sorry, but your solution (which I already tried) doesn't work. because though the name suggests runtimeConfig, it's static (during compilation time). If i build with a stage .env, it'll contain stage apiHost regardless of how I run the server with NODE_ENV. process.env.<anything> does not compute at runtime :/ this is computed during compilation time sadly.